# How to write Junits for class implementing dynamic feature interface of jersey?

Tags: java, junit, jersey, mockito

1.How to write junits for this class using mockito?

```
public class Jerseybinding implements DynamicFeature{

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        if (SomeImpl.class.equals(resourceInfo.getResourceClass()) || SomeResource.class.equals(resourceInfo.getClass())) {
            context.register(new ExampleFilter(new ExampleMatcher()));
        }
    }

}
```

I have written the junit but it is throwing error when i'm trying to return to return SomeResource.class.

```
public class JerseybindingTest { 
  public void before(){ 
    resourceInfo = Mockito.mock(ResourceInfo.class); 
    info = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class); 
    featureContext = Mockito.mock(FeatureContext.class); 
  } 
  @Test 
  public void testBind() {     
    Mockito.when(resourceInfo.getClass()).thenReturn(SomeResourc‌​e.class); // this line also shows error when I return anything.class
    Mockito.when(featureContext.register(Mockito.class)).thenRet‌​urn(featureContext);‌​// same here 
    Jerseybinding.configure(resourceInfo,featureContext);
  }
}
```

Comment: The same way you'd write any other test? Mock out `FeatureContext` and assert that `register` is called?

Comment: I have edited your question to add the information for your comment. There is a link called 'edit' at the bottom of your question for you to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to write the junit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to mock out the `FeatureContext` and assert that `register` is called as expected.

Something along the lines of:

```
@Test
public void testConfigure() {
  SomeImpl resourceInfo = ... ; // create a new instance of SomeImpl, or mock it if needed

  // prepare your mock
  FeatureContext context = Mockito.mock(FeatureContext.class);
  Mockito.doNothing().when(context).register(Mockito.any(ExampleFilter.class));

  // invoke the method under test
  JerseyBinding binding = new JerseyBinding();
  binding.configure(resourceInfo, context);

  // verify that we called register
  Mockito.verify(context).register(Mockito.any(ExampleFilter.class));

  // verify nothing else was called on the context
  Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(context);
}
```

Alternatively you can also use an ArgumentCaptor if you want to validate the particulars of what is passed into the `register` method.

---

- If `register` is a void method, you can use `Mockito.doNothing().register(...)` as in the example.
- If `register` is not a void method, use `Mockito.doReturn(null).register(...)` instead.

Comment: doNothing() is called for void methods. register() is not a void method.

Comment: So use `doReturn(null)`. I've never used this Jersey library, and this question and answer have nothing to do with the library either -- it's a straight up how-do-i-mock-this sort of question.

Comment: Mockito.verify(context).register(Mockito.any(ExampleFilter.class));// it is throwing an exception that there is no interaction with this mock.

Comment: So your test failed.

Comment: it is failing becuase inside the configure() method if statement evaluates to false as resourceinfo.getResourceClass() is not equal to SomeImpl.class. how can we  do something like this :   ResourceInfo resourceInfo = Mockito.mock(ResourceInfo.class) ; 
    Mockito.when(resourceInfo.getResourceClass()).thenReturn(SomeImpl.class) // this statement shows error